# getReadableDatabase and getWriteableDatabase won't resolve

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been trying to figure out why "getWritableDatabase" and "getReadableDatabase" won't resolve. I used a feeder from my database. I've inserted all the code from my MainActivity and database if anyone is willing to decipher through it and give me their advice. I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

**Main Activity**

```
                 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String TAG = "MainActivity";
private ListView  listView ;
DBHelper mydb;
ArrayList<Call_log> calls = new ArrayList();
MyAdapter adapter;
SearchView searchView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mydb = new DBHelper();
    clear_db();

    getCallDetails();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

    ArrayList<Call_log> array_list= get();
    adapter =  new MyAdapter(this, array_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},20);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            adapter.items =  adapter.filter(query);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.items =  adapter.filter(newText);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });

}



private String getCallDetails() {

    StringBuffer call = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);

    int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int name_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = cursor.getString(number);
        String callType = cursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = cursor.getString(date);
        String name = cursor.getString(name_index);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
        String call_type = null;
        int call_type_indicator = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (call_type_indicator) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                call_type = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                call_type = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                call_type = "MISSED";
                break;
        }

        insert(name,phNumber, call_type, callDuration);
    }

    Log.d("MainActivity","calls: "+call);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        call.append("\n No calls in record");
    }
    cursor.close();
    return call.toString();

}
public void insert(String name, String phone, String call_type, String duration  ) {
    // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
   values.put(DBHelper.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PHONE, phone);
   values.put(COLUMN_CALL_TYPE, call_type);
    values.put(DBHelper.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DURATION, duration);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mydb.getWritableDatabase();
    // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
    long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

public void delete(String phone, int i){
    Log.d(TAG, "deleting "+phone);
    
   SQLiteDatabase db_r = mydb.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "delete  from "+TABLE_NAME + " WHERE phone = "+phone;
    Cursor cursor = db_r.rawQuery( sql, null );
    adapter.items.remove(i);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    StringBuffer call = new StringBuffer();


    cursor.close();


}
 public void getWhereLike(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db_r = mydb.getReadableDatabase();
   // How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
    String sortOrder =
            COLUMN_NAME + " DESC";
    Cursor cursor = db_r.rawQuery( "select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE (name LIKE "+name+" + '%')", null );

}



public  ArrayList<Call_log> get(){
    SQLiteDatabase db_r = mydb.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db_r.rawQuery( "select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY "+COLUMN_NAME, null );
    ArrayList<Call_log> array_list = new ArrayList();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int i = 0;
    while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false){
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
        String phone =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_PHONE));
        String call_type =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CALL_TYPE));
        String duration =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DURATION));
        String date =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DATE));
        Call_log call = new Call_log(call_type,date ,phone, duration, name);
        array_list.add(call);
        calls.add(call);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        i++;
    }

    cursor.close();
    return array_list;
}

public void clear_db(){
    SQLiteDatabase db_r = mydb.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "delete from "+ TABLE_NAME;
    db_r.execSQL(sql);
}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList <Call_log> items;

    public MyAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<Call_log> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }
    public ArrayList filter(String query){
        ArrayList <Call_log> newItems = new ArrayList<>();
        if(query.length() > 0){
            for(Call_log log : calls){
                String name = log.caller_name != null ? log.caller_name: "Unknown";
                if (log.phone.contains(query) || name.contains(query)){
                    newItems.add(log);
                }
            }
            if(newItems.size() < 1){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Match found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }else {
            newItems = calls;
        }
        return newItems;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // inflate the layout for each list row
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                    inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, viewGroup, false);
        }
        // get current item to be displayed
        Call_log currentItem = (Call_log) getItem(i);
        // get the TextView for item name and item description
        TextView name =  view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView phone =  view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        TextView type =  view.findViewById(R.id.type);
        Button row_erase = (Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.row_erase);
        //sets the text for item name and item description from the current item object
        String t =  currentItem.getCaller_name() != null ?  currentItem.getCaller_name(): "Unknown";

        name.setText(t);
        phone.setText(currentItem.getPhone() != null ? currentItem.getPhone(): "Unknown");
        type.setText(currentItem.getType() != null? currentItem.getType() : "Unknown");

        row_erase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                delete(currentItem.phone, i);
            }
        });

        // returns the view for the current row
        return view;
    }
}


 }
```

**DBHelper**

```
      package com.example.lab10.db;

        import android.content.ContentValues;
       import android.content.Context;
       import android.database.Cursor;
      import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
     import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
  import android.provider.BaseColumns;

      import com.example.lab10.bean.Call_log;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

 public class DBHelper {



private static final String TAG=DBHelper.class.getSimpleName();




public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "MyDBName.mydb";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String LOG_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Table_Log";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String COLUMN_CALL_TYPE = "call_type";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DURATION = "duration";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DATE = "date";


    //create table table_todo(task_id integer primary key
    private static String CREATE_TABLE_TODO = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +    COLUMN_NAME + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_NAME_PHONE + " TEXT ," + COLUMN_CALL_TYPE + " TEXT ," + COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DURATION + " TEXT ," + COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DATE + " TEXT )";

    private Context context;
    public SQLiteDatabase sqLliteDatabase;
    public static DBHelper DBHelperInstance;


    public void DBHelper(FeedEntry feedEntry) {
        sqLliteDatabase = new DBAdapter(this.context, DB_NAME, null,    DB_VERSION).getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public static DBHelper getDBHelperInstance(Context context) {
        if (DBHelperInstance == null) {
            DBHelperInstance = new DBHelper();
        }

        return DBHelperInstance;
    }
    
    
    
     //insert,delete,modify,query methods

    public boolean insert(String phone, String call_type, String duration, String date) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME_PHONE, phone);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CALL_TYPE, call_type);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DURATION, duration);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DATE, date);


        return sqLliteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues) > 0;
    }

    public boolean delete(String phone) {

        return sqLliteDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME + " = " + phone, null) > 0;
    }

    public boolean modify(String name, String newPhone, String newCall_type, String newDuration, String newDate) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME_PHONE, newPhone);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CALL_TYPE, newCall_type);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DURATION, newDuration);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME_CALL_DATE, newDate);

        return sqLliteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, COLUMN_NAME + " = " + name,   null) > 0;
    }

    public List<Call_log> getAllCallLogs() {
        List<Call_log> calls = new ArrayList<Call_log>();

        Cursor cursor = sqLliteDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COLUMN_NAME,    COLUMN_NAME_PHONE}, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null & cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Call_log logs = new Call_log(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1),      cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
                calls.add(logs);


            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return calls;
    }

    private static class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBAdapter(Context context, String databaseName, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int dbVersion) {
            super(context, databaseName, factory, dbVersion);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onConfigure(db);
            db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TODO);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase,
                              int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            //Not implemented now
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It can not resolve this because your `mydb` is an instance of `DBHelper` class owned by you. It should be an instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` to call `getWritableDatabase` & `getReadableDatabase` methods.

You can create a public field for `SQLiteOpenHelper` inside your `DBHelper` class or a getter method to get database.